# Twilio Studio beta Flow with sequence of Send and Wait for Reply actions

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to string together several Send and Wait for Reply actions with a Twilio Studio beta Flow? I am trying to ask the recipient a sequence of questions, one by one, with potential branching using the Split action, and then finally make an HTTP request back to my server with the answers from all the questions. I trigger the start of the flow with a REST call and the first action of the flow works (the first Send and Wait for Reply action) but after replying to the message, the flow doesn't continue on to the next step.

Is this capability supported?

Do you have to do anything special with the phone number configuration (Webhook or Studio Flow config for incoming message)?

BTW, a sequence of Send actions works fine to deliver several messages in a row. The problem comes from using the Send and Wait for Reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You definitely can do this! This might not have been the case when you asked this question, but if you go into [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard) and create a new flow there are a bunch of templates. One of the templates is an SMS Survey, which is pretty much what you're asking here, a bunch of questions split on responses and finish by sending them to your server.

Check that out and let me know if you have any questions.