# In Twilio Studio flow 'Send & Wait for reply' Widget is not working as expected

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm creating a flow in Twilio studio beta tool from scratch which gets triggered by rest API, in which I'm facing a problem with 'send & wait for reply' widget sequence as a first widget successfully executing but not calling the next widget. As I tried to attach widget for all possible output of 'send & wait for reply' widget but always get result for 'no reply' output.

I have taken the reference from this https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/sending-sms-messages-process-builder

And as per this question's ([Twilio Studio beta Flow with sequence of Send and Wait for Reply actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925488/twilio-studio-beta-flow-with-sequence-of-send-and-wait-for-reply-actions)) solution, I have matched my flow with existing sms survey flow template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you associate the Twilio number your flow is using as the From (outbound CallerID) with the this Studio flow (Under Messaging > A Message Comes In), so when someone sends a response, it gets sent back to your Studio Flow.

You do this here, https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming, when logged into your Twilio console.

Studio is a Generally Available (GA) Product, no longer Beta.

Also, the execution logs for the Studio flow are useful for providing additional insight into flow behavior.

Comment: yeah @Alan you are right I have to configure messaging for Twilio active phone number like  (Under Messaging > A Message Comes In>Studio flow)

Comment: can we send and receive an image via Twilio studio chatbot?

Comment: yes, you fill in the MediaURL:
Media URL

The URL of the media you wish you send out with the message (i.e. https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png)

Comment: Also make sure the Twilio number you are using is not associated with a messaging service.

Comment: @RobMcKee Thank you! But now with A2P campaign regulation, you have to add phone number into a P2A campaign verified Message Service, otherwise, your message could be blocked.

Comment: Get answer from Twilio, if you send sms via message service, or you added your phone number into a message service, use Message Service Sig as from, not the phone number, in that way, the "send and wait for reply" widget will collect the user reply.